# Transfering Matlab scripts into python

Tags: python, matlab, spyder, translate, transfer

I have a number of Matlab functions and scripts which have been developed over a couple of years. I want to continue using these scripts, but can't afford MatLab. That's why I would like to transfer them to python. Is there an easy way to do this? I am a beginner in Python and I have Spyder 3.7 installed on my computer.

Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, I don't think so. I had to convert a matlab code for my thesis few days ago. It will take you few hours if you know your python but since you said you are a beginner, it is going to be a tough one

Comment: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/402284-matlab-to-python-conversion check this

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I couldn't install the translator, I think the installation is done in Linux, I am using windows... Oh I have over 20 long scripts... I think that would take me many days if I had to do it manually :(

Answer (score 3):

You can try Octave - an open source free Matlab equivalent.
If you can run your functions and scripts in Octave, then you can call them from within Python using `oct2py` package in Python.

Look e.g. [here](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/oct2py-and-gnu-octave/).

By that, you wouldn't have to translate any code into another language (like Python), which would mean you could introduce new bugs which then you have to debug etc etc ...

Comment: That is good to know! Then I can even run my codes directly in Octave right?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, if not too fancy code.

Comment: Cool, I will give it a go! Thank you for the tip :)